# Unused lines in RGB linescan sensor

Tags: ccd

For the exploration of a CCD line scan sensor, I would like to ignore two colors on an RGB sensor. What should I do? Just not connect clocks and outputs? Tie them to ground?

The sensor in question is a PD3728DZ from NEC. The datasheet ist here:

http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/1451098/pd3728dz_renesas-electronics.html

I am not even sure what to look for in there. I would appreciate any help you cand give me.

Comment: think about this `are all CCD line scan sensor modules the same?` .... do you think that you provided adequate information?

Comment: oops. true. that's a good point. sorry. i wrote another related question a little while before that, and it has the details, but, you're absolutely right. i'm gonna add some details.